# Is the directory that a file-system is mounted on (mount point) a device file of the file system's type?

Tags: filesystems, devices

A device file is an interface to the device driver of the device.

When we mount a file system to a directory, is the directory considered a device file (of the file system's type)?

If the  directory  is not a device file, does the driver of the file system's type have a corresponding device file somewhere?

If the  directory  is  a device file, how does the  directory  can be seen as the device file of the driver of the file system's type?

Answer (score 1):

If you do:

```
mount -t type /dev/somedev /dir/somedir
```

you mount the device file `somedev` on the directory `somedir`. `somedir` is and stays a directory, the access to the device "redirects" via the mount point to the `somedev` device. To answer your second question ( `have corresponding device file somewhere`) directly: yes it does it is `somedev` that you use for mounting.

Comment: (1) is `somedir` like a link to `somedev`? (2) For several devices of the same type, can they share the same driver, and therefore the same device file? Or they share the same driver, but have their distinct device files?

Comment: No it is not a link, as that is something that exists on the filesystem level. This is mapping maintained by the kernel. The code is of course reused, what code is used is determined at mount time, by specifying `-t type` or by analysis of the device (contents) by the mount program.

Comment: "No it is a link", you mean it is or it is not a link? On what level does a link exists?

Comment: @tim sorry, should have read what I wrote, corrected it to "No it is not a link, ..."

Comment: The device may or not be a symbolic link. However this is not used to implement multiple devices for one driver. symbolic links are used to give multiple names to a single device. It is the minor and major numbers that are the links that you @Tim have suggested. Do `ls -lF /dev | less`, you will see that each device has to numbers. The first number is the major number, this links to a device driver. The second is the minor number, this specifies the particular device.